# Determining which route would be used for a request URL

Tags: python, flask

In the Flask framework, I would like to be able to determine which request route would be selected to serve a URL, without having to actually request the URL itself. For example, if I have an app like:

```py
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    pass

@app.route('/<id:int>')
@app.route('/<id:int>-<slug>')
def show_page(id, slug = None):
    pass
```

then I'd like to be able to do something like (fictional example):

```
route = app.get_url_rule("/12345")
```

and get a result like:

```
('show_page', {'id':12345,'slug':None})
```

As far as I can tell, Flask doesn't expose any functionality like this on its own, but is there a way to possibly dig down into its request routing layer (or possibly Werkzeug) to implement this myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you're looking for is exactly what Flask does for routing, through Werkzeug. When you decorate view functions, the rules are registered in an instance of [`werkzeug.routing.Map`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Map). When the app handles a request, the map is bound to the request to create a [`MapAdapter`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/routing/#werkzeug.routing.MapAdapter). The adapter has a [`match()`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/routing/#werkzeug.routing.MapAdapter.match) method which either returns an `endpoint, args` match or raises a routing error such as 307, 404, or 405. Flask call this and uses the result to call the appropriate view function.

Call [`app.create_url_adapter()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Flask.create_url_adapter) to get an adapter based on the app configuration. When not in a request, this requires configuring `SERVER_NAME`. Then call `adapter.match(url)` to get a match. This example ignores routing exceptions and returns None.

```py
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

# remember to configure app.config["SERVER_NAME"]

def match_url(url):
    adapter = app.get_url_adapter()
    
    try:
        return adapter.match(url)
    except HTTPException:
        return None
```

Calling `match_url("/12345-example")` returns `('show_page', {'id': 12345, 'slug': 'example'})`.

Note that this normally isn't useful, as the point of Flask is that it will already do the routing and call the appropriate view.

Answer (score -1):

I tried Davidism's method with your route code, in case this helps...

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<int:id>')
@app.route('/<int:id>-<slug>')
def show_page(id, slug = None):
    adapter = app.create_url_adapter(request)
    endpoint, values = adapter.match()
    
    # Return this to frontend of ease of demo
    return {endpoint: values}
```

A request to `/123` returns:

```
{
  "show_page": {
    "id": 123
  }
}
```

A request to `/123-abc` returns:

```
{
  "show_page": {
    "id": 123, 
    "slug": "abc"
  }
}
```